# Rearrange a string in R Studio

Tags: r, string

I have something like this

```
a <- "good day"
```

I want to rearrange it based on space:

```
a <- "day good"
```

or rearrange it based on "-"

```
"a good-day" >>>> "a day-good"
```

I prefer to generalize it because I have a big dataset.

Comment: It would help if you could make your logic clearer. Do you always want to switch the words? Or do you want to sort the words alphabetically? Or, when you say *"based on `"good-day" >>>> "day-good"`", do you have this somewhere else with hyphens and somehow this data tells you the order you want? If so, where is it, what is the data structure, and what does it mean? Is `>>>>` significant? Do you want hyphens always, or only if there were hyphens to start?

Comment: Maybe try `strsplit` to split the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
> paste(rev(strsplit(a," ")[[1]]),collapse=" ")
[1] "day good"
```

Comment: It worked, thanks! However, if I have data like this "a good-day", I want the result to be "a day-good". Only change order based on "-". Do you know how to do it? Your code with collapse = "-" would give me "day-good-a".

Comment: @vicky That's a different problem then. How many words can you have? How many spaces? How many "-"? In what order?

Answer (score 1):

```
string <- c("good-day")
gsub("(\\w+)-(\\w+)", "\\2-\\1", string)
[1] "day-good"
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that there are two words containing only word characters and separated by non-word characters:

```
x <- c("good day", "good-day")
sub("(\\w+)(\\W+)(\\w+)", "\\3\\2\\1", x)
## [1] "day good" "day-good"
```

See `?regex` for more information.